# How to delete item from an array of object using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

i wanted to delete index from array if rest service response return true , so in below case lets say we have true from rest service i wanted to delete object where id is 'RA_ATTST_LANGUAGE` from array. I tried below code but its not deleting what is missing ?

main.js

```
MessageAdminNotificationFactory.getAttestationLanValidation().then(function(response){
        var data = response.data;
        console.log('attestation',data);
        if(data){
          angular.forEach($scope.adminDataSource,function(value,$index){
            if(value.id === 'RA_ATTST_LANGUAGE'){
              $scope.adminDataSource.splice($index, 1);
            }
            console.log('dropdown',value.id);
          });
        }
      });

$scope.adminDataSource = [{
    "uid": null,
    "index": 0,
    "selected": null,
    "expanded": null,
    "id": "RA_PLTFRM_NOTIF",
    "text": "Platform Maintenance Notification",
    "parentId": null,
    "items": null
}, {
    "uid": null,
    "index": 0,
    "selected": null,
    "expanded": null,
    "id": "RA_ATTST_LANGUAGE",
    "text": "Attestation Language",
    "parentId": null,
    "items": null
}]
```

Comment: you're modifying an array as you iterate over its index. Not sure if that is the cause but you should never do that. at least break the loop if you do. But you should prob use Array.filter

Comment: This really has nothing to do with angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.adminDataSource = $scope.adminDataSource.filter(
  function(value){
     return value.id !== 'RA_ATTST_LANGUAGE';
})
```

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is the way to go. filters out anything that evaluates to false;

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array from end to start

```
for(var i=$scope.adminDataSource.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    var value = $scope.adminDataSource[i];
    if(value.id === 'RA_ATTST_LANGUAGE') {
       $scope.adminDataSource.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

This way it doesn't matter if the array shrinks while you iterate.

Comment: Avoid using let if question is not tagged es6?

Comment: You're right. Just a typescript habit of mine. TS transpiles let into var.

Comment: and now stack overflow has 3 more questions... let?  es6? typescript? :)